# what am i missing for this function?

Tags: python, python-3.8

I am trying to get the input for when it says "how many burgers do you want" but I don't get that option when I run the program. what am I missing in the main function? no errors pop up when I run the program either.

```
def main():
      endProgram = 'no'

      while endProgram == 'no': 
        totalFry = 0
        totalBurger = 0
        totalSoda = 0 
        endOrder = 'no'
        while endOrder == 'no':
          print ('Enter 1 for Yum Yum Burger')
          print ('Enter 2 for Grease Yum Fries')
          print ('Enter 3 for Soda Yum')
          option = input('Enter now -> ')
          if option == 1:
            totalBurger = getBurger(totalBurger)
          elif option == 2: 
            totalFry = getFries(totalFry)
          elif option == 3:
            totalSoda = getSoda(totalSoda)
          endOrder = input ('would you like to end your order? Enter No if you want to order more items: ')

        total = calcTotal(totalBurger, totalFry, totalSoda)
        printRecipt(total)

        endProgram= input ('do you want to end program? (enter no to process new order)')


    def getBurger(totalBurger):
      burgerCount = input ('enter number of burgers you want: ')
      totalBurger = totalBurgers + burgerCount * .99
      return totalBurgers

    def getFry(totalFry):
      fryCount = input ('Enter How Many Fries You want: ')
      totalFry = totalFries + fryCount * .79
      return totalFries

    def getSoda(totalSoda):
      sodaCount = input('enter number of sodas you would want: ')
      totalSoda = totalSoda + sodaCount * 1.09
      return totalSoda

    def calcTotal(totalBurger, totalFry, totalSoda):
      subTotal = totalBurger + totalFry + totalSoda
      tax = subTotal * .06
      total = subTotal + tax
      return total

    def printRecipt(total):
      print ('your total is $', total)

    main()
```

Comment: thank you everyone! the int fixed the issue!!

Comment: if the answer helped you fix your problem could you mark it as accepted?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
if option == 1:
```

try:

```
if options == '1'
```

or you can do:

```
option = int(input('Enter now -> ')
```

the input returns a string not an int thus the if statements aren't being triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing strings and int in your comparison

For example in your code:

```
 option = input('Enter now -> ')
 if option == 1:
     totalBurger = getBurger(totalBurger)
```

the value returned by input( ) is **always** a string so when you compare
it to an integer (1) the results is **always** False

If you want to use the user input as an integer you need to convert it to
one first:

```
 option = input('Enter now -> ')
 option = int(option)
 if option == 1:
     totalBurger = getBurger(totalBurger)
```

You'll need to make similar changes for your other input() calls

Comment: what should I do to fix this? Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\CISP 300\Lab\Lab5-5.pyfile.py", line 53, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\CISP 300\Lab\Lab5-5.pyfile.py", line 16, in main
    totalBurger = getBurger(totalBurger)
  File "D:\CISP 300\Lab\Lab5-5.pyfile.py", line 31, in getBurger
    totalBurger = (totalBurger + burgerCount) * .99
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: This is the same problem as in your initial question.  Whenever you get something from input() it is going to be a STRING so this case you are try to add a STRING to an INTEGER which is why you get the TypeError exception - the plus (+) operator is saying it doesn't know how to add a STRING to an INTEGER.

So as I mentioned in my answer you need to convert the return value from input() into an INTEGER everywhere in your code.  So in this case:

burgerCount = int(input ('enter number of burgers you want: '))

would do the trick

Answer (score 0):

The line `option = input('Enter now -> ')` takes the value as a string.

When you are checking for `option==1` you are comparing an integer with a string. That is the reason why none of the conditions pass and you are not able to take further inputs.

Try replacing `option = input('Enter now -> ')` 
with `option = int(input('Enter now -> '))` and it should work fine.